# Servlets and JSP blank

Tags: java, database, servlets

hi all I've typed out a page that queries the database then inputs something into the database but when I go to load the servlet/jsp page its comes back blank and am unsure what is happening or why? I'm coding in eclipse and after looking at the console and not getting anything printing out I figured there was something wrong with my code but I cannot see the problem.

Here is my servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TutorAssign
 */
@WebServlet("/TutorAssign")
public class TutorAssign extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TutorAssign() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void sendBack(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            //Set data you want to send back to the request (will be forwarded to the page)
            //Can set string, int, list, array etc.

         String sql = "SELECT l.id,s.name,l.day,l.time,l.room" +
                  " FROM subject s, lab l " +
                    " WHERE s.user_id="+(Integer)session.getAttribute("id");

          try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
            System.out.println("got boobs");
            System.out.println(session.getAttribute("id"));

              Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
              System.out.println(res);
              ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
              ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
              if (res.next()){
                  do{
                       list1.add(res.getString(1));
                       list2.add(res.getString(2)+" "+res.getString(3)+" "+res.getString(4)+" "+res.getString(5));


                  }while(res.next());
              System.out.println("Outside");
              String[] arr1 = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
              String[] arr2 = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
              System.out.println(list1);
              request.setAttribute("res1", arr1);
              request.setAttribute("res2", arr2);

              }



          }catch (SQLException e) {
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            } 


            //Decides what page to send the request data to
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("TutorAssign.jsp");
            //Forward to the page and pass the request and response information
            view.forward(request, response); 
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


          int user_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
          int lab_id = 0;

          String message = null; 
          try {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection con = 
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
            System.out.println("got connection"); 
            System.out.println(user_id);
            Statement s = con.createStatement(); 

            String sql = "INSERT INTO user_lab" + 
                      " (user_id, lab_id)" + 
                      " VALUES" + 
                      " ('" +  user_id + "'," + 
                         " '"  +  lab_id + "')"; 

              System.out.println(sql);
              int i = s.executeUpdate(sql); 
              if (i==1) {
                message = "Successfully assigned a tutor."; 
                response.sendRedirect("Lecturer_labs");
              } 

              s.close(); 
              con.close(); 
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) {
              message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
              boolean error = true; 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
              message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
              boolean error = true; 
            } 
            if (message!=null) {
              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
              out.println("<B>" + message + "</B><BR>"); 
              out.println("<HR><BR>"); 
            } 

          } 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

Comment: How are you loading your servlet??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your doGet method has not been implemented. 
I would assume that your sendBack code is not being called

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   sendBack(request,response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several empty catch blocks.  This means that if the program encounters some problem the error will be silently swallowed and you don't know what code got executed and what code was skipped, so the outcome is unknown.  At least log the error in the catch block, like this (very basic example, using [java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"SQL Error encountered",e);        
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Other error encountered",e);        
}
```

Start by getting your error handling right, and study the errors the program encounters.

Aside from that problem, as the others point out your `doGet` isn't implemented - so if you call the page with `GET` it won't do anything because `doGet` is empty.  It should do something on `POST` though.